# How to design supporting strut for 4-piece rock and roll bed

Tags: design, plywood

I am making a 4-piece 'rock and roll' style bed which converts into two opposite facing bench seats when in the upright position.  Constructed out of 18mm ply with supporting structural members where required.  Images from Sketchup included at the bottom

When in the upright position, I want the backrest to be stable.  To some extent the triangulation of the two vertical ply members will provide some stability, but I am worried that there will still be a lot of movement (or bounce if you like) as I have made the design so that, at minimum extension of the bed platform, the angle of the backrests is ~75-80 degrees from horizontal.

There is not a lot of room below the top level of framing and the internal cavity underneath as I will be using this space to house drawers so I want to minimise the bulk of any supporting strut that i add to achieve my objective.

I am thinking that I will need a cross-brace between the two backrests to provide support, or a brace from one of the backrests back to a solid point attached to the framing.

How can i do this in a way that will minimise bulk, be easy to use/retract and fold back to flush when the bed is in the extended position?

[image: model]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Is there a piano hinge going along the joint at the peak? You mention image**s** but there's only one showing so maybe this is included in the missing pics, but that alone might be enough here assuming the rest is stable. Anyway, I think this might be the type of thing where it's better to build it first, see how stable it turns out to be and problem solve from there. Looking at it in the theoretical it's very easy to overthink it, and while overbuilding is normally no bad thing it adds cost, and you presumably want to avoid going heavier/more awkward than needed.

Comment: If anything, I would add a skirt board to the pieces that bend upward to help reduce flex in the plywood. If the two skirt boards are mitered at the 75°-80° angle so that they meet precisely at the point, they should help prevent the back from moving much.

Comment: Those skirt boards could be supplemented with a couple of boards between the edges (spaced evenly), each with the appropriate angles to meet at the middle. These would provide some additional rigidity to the plywood across its span to help prevent sag when it's in "bed mode".

Comment: @Graphus :  I had considered using piano hinges, and I agree that if I did that they would probably provide enough rigidity to support the vertices of the triangle when the bed is in the upright position, and would be optimal at an angle of ~45 degrees. I am considering to use a length of webbing/ratchet strap crewed along the edges of the boards to create the hinge, instead of using a hinge proper, to make the movement effectively silent and frictionless, but this would also allow for much more movement/play in the mechanism which is the primary reason for thinking about a supporting brace.

Comment: @Graphus : I agree, I should probably just build it and then improve it :)

Comment: @FreeMan : Thank you for your comments, yes I agree that a mitred skirt/edge board would provide support in chair mode at maximum backrest angle.  The ply panel which remains horizontal and extends to convert from bench- to bed- mode is on heavy duty drawer runners and I also want the ability to recline the bench at increments (using dowels or something to hold the runners somewhere along their mid stroke) and so the skirt boards would not provide any additional support in this case.

Comment: @FreeMan : Again, I should probably just build it and see, given that the triangulation effect will provide increasing support at lower backrest angles :)

Comment: You may want to consider posting an answer after your build test to let readers know how it went and what you would do differently.  Good Luck

Comment: Webbing hinge could be enough as long as there's minimal slack. My gut read is that given you're using 18mm ply if the bottom edges are prevented from moving at all in this orientation, and the top is held even fairly firmly, then this could work as-is. My thinking is there should be very little flex (since the triangle can't distort more than a teeny bit, and each piece of ply isn't free to flex as it could if completely unsupported) and that could feel stable enough that it won't bother users. Easy to add something later if this turns out not to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using piano hinges and the backrests are self supporting and don't move at all.  Very happy with the outcome.

As a side note, I routed grooves to reduce weight and add airflow.  this process took a long time and was a huge PITA - I can now see the value of a CNC mill! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for posting back about what worked out. Looks excellent, nice job!

Comment: The curved edge of the vehicle in the first pic made me think the picture was taken with a fish-eye lens. It took me a minute to get my head wrapped around that... Yes, that does look very nice. Well done and another thanks for posting your results!